# TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) With Django third party package Models

Tags: python, django

I installed the django_message package into my django app using django 2.0 and while it works on my development machine, it throws the following errors on production when I try to open the list of messages from Django Admin console.

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
[22/Mar/2019 15:08:12] ERROR [django.request:118] Internal Server Error: /admin/django_messages/message/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 574, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 62, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 58, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1570, in changelist_view
    cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 705, in get_changelist_instance
    self,
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 76, in __init__
    self.queryset = self.get_queryset(request)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 320, in get_queryset
    filters_use_distinct) = self.get_filters(request)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 130, in get_filters
    self.model, self.model_admin, field_path=field_path
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/filters.py", line 157, in create
    return list_filter_class(field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path=field_path)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/filters.py", line 168, in __init__
    self.lookup_choices = self.field_choices(field, request, model_admin)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/filters.py", line 195, in field_choices
    return field.get_choices(include_blank=False)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 812, in get_choices
    limit_choices_to)]
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 811, in <listcomp>
    for x in rel_model._default_manager.complex_filter(
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 34, in smart_text
    return force_text(s, encoding, strings_only, errors)
  File "/opt/site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 67, in force_text
    s = str(s)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

The biggest concern is that this is not the only model that is throwing the error. I have the same from django-allauth throwing the same error with SocialAccount.

Another concern is that I don't think I should be fixing the codes from this packages but I am left with nothing else.

Also to note, that none of the models for the application itself causes these error. 
Only applies to django_allauth and django_messages. However, the failure doesn't happen in my development machine.
The mysql table for django_messages is empty (without records). 
Is there a config that causes these kinds of errors or somethings.
I am using django 2.0 and python 3.6 in both enviroments.

Comment: Are you using this https://github.com/arneb/django-messages? If so, looking at Messge model(https://github.com/arneb/django-messages/blob/master/django_messages/models.py) it seems that "subject" field is empty for any record in your production db table.

Comment: Thanks @ydrall, but the production dB table is empty. There are no records in it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out.

It turns out that all the models failing are related to the User model whose **str**() method points to a field that has its database column as NULLs.

Solution: I have to make that field not nullable at the database level and at django level by assigning default value at the pre_save phase.

It worked.